# I accidentally wrote wrong file name in command and file has deleted

Tags: c, gcc, clion

I wanted running a c program through the terminal, and instead of writing the following: `gcc -o main.c program.c`
,
I have written the following: `gcc -o main,c program.c`. This unfortunately disappeared my file "program.c", perhaps deleted it, and created a new txt file called "main,c" which looks like that:

[image]

Now, I have searched a lot this issue over a few sites and I couldn't find a compatible case for this one. Is there a way to recover the c file?

- In addition, all remained is program.c.o file and main,c file.

Thanks!

Comment: Which file are you trying to recover? The original `program.c` file should still be there. Also, are you sure `gcc -o main.c program.c` is the command you want? That will try to compile `program.c` into a binary called `main.c` which doesn't seem right. The question is somewhat confusing.

Comment: That command would not have deleted the `main.c` file. But the GCC command you you typed would compile `program.c` into an object file `main,c` which is almost certainly not what you want. I doubt that forensically recovering `main.c` is the best approach here. It's probably better to learn to back-up or version control your stuff.

Comment: @kaylum
I am trying to recover program.c 
if it's still there why can't I find it anywhere on the computer?

I am sure that this is the command I used, and after that I used ./main.c to see the prints.

Comment: @Cheatah  I wrote the command wrong and the main,c created instead of main.c

Comment: *"why can't I find it anywhere on the computer*". We can't answer that as nothing in the info you have given would have deleted program.c. "*I am sure that this is the command*". Ok but it is unusual to name an executable with a `.c` suffix. On Linux, executables are typically without suffix. So just `gcc -o main program.c`.

Comment: Why would you think that `gcc -o main.c program.c` would be ok but `gcc -o main,c program.c` would somehow delete program.c?

Comment: @kaylum because after that the program has disappeared.

Comment: You are jumping to the wrong conclusion. Multiple comments have told you that neither command will delete program.c.

Comment: You would not in any case want to have created `main.c` by compiling `program.c`.  The output of the compiler/linker is a binary executable, not a C source file.  Why would you call your executable `.c`?  That will only cause confusion.

Comment: @kaylum 
I will clarify this, I wrote code on program.c, and I wanted running it over the terminal. Now, I am a new Mac user, and that's why I did the extension .c to the main. It worked wonderfully until I accidentally wrote ',' instead of '.', then the file removed.

Comment: _"I am a new Mac user, and that's why I did the extension .c to the main"_ - None of that statement makes any kind of sense - it is entirely non-sequitur.  Why would being new to Mac cause you to do that?  GCC is GCC on any platform, and on no platform would that have been appropriate.  Also I am not sure why you are addressing Kaylum with that response.  A little clarity of though is required I think.

Answer (score 2):

Recovering the original source file is not a programming question, it is a general computing issue.  With any tool (word-processor, photo-editor or as in this case a compiler), if you rewrite a file, the original is replaced and so no longer available.

You seem very confused over how to drive the compiler - the action you said you have taken would not on its own caused the results you state;  I suspect in your confusion you have taken other actions that have simply worsened your situation.

*Neither* command line would have been correct in any case.  The `-o` option specifies the *output* file name, and in the first case it would have created or overwritten `main.c`, and in the second it would have *created* `main,c`.

If you only executed the second command, `main,c` will have been created, and `main.c` will still exist.  Neither of those commands will have *deleted* anything, but may have overwritten the sourcefile with object code file rendering it useless.

It is not clear what you were actually trying to do, but if you were trying to compile `main.c` to create program called `program`, then:

```
gcc -o program main.c
```

If however you were trying to compile and link two source files called `main.c` and `program.c` to create an executable, then:

```
gcc -o program main.c program.c
```

or even:

```
gcc -c main.c 
gcc -c program.c
gcc -o main.o program.o
```

---

From the comments it seems in fact you are attempting to compile `program.c` to create an executable called `main.c`.  Don't do that!  The .c extension is used to indicate a C *source file* - *input* to the compiler).  The *output* of the compiler is binary object code (and following the implicit *link* a binary *executable*).  What you need then is simply:

```
gcc -o program program.c
```

None of that explains how you managed to delete `program.c` or even create a file called `program.c.o` rather then simply `program.o` - "the steps to reproduce" provided are not plausible.  You have clearly made a string of erroneous actions to end up where you are.  Unpicking it is probably unproductive; it is gone, you must start again, take care, use the compiler correctly and perhaps make a back-up copy or use a version control system before experimenting further.

Comment: FWIW, in the comments OP has said the intention is to compile the source `program.c` into the executable `main.c` (yes I agree it doesn't make sense).

Comment: @kaylum :  Yes - spotted that - even more confused that any reasonable person could imagine!

Comment: @Clifford but how can I now get the source file back? all I have on clion is the "main,c" and "main.c" files and both are encoded.

Comment: @Chopin :  I thought I made that clear - that is a "how to use a computer" question not a "how to use a compiler" question, so off topic on SO.  But the simple answer is probably you can't.  If it is gone, it is gone.  It is hard to see how you deleted it however  the information you have provided on how you ended up in this state is clearly incomplete.

Comment: @Clifford I understand, but I told what I done step by step completely.

Comment: @Chopin ... Clion is simply an IDE.  Did you actually look at the filesystem rather then simply the IDE project file list?  What is not clear to me is that if you were using Clion, how come you even ended up using the command line directly in any case?  An IDE allows you to avoid the command line and protects you from your own incompetence.

Comment: @Chopin : Repeat the steps and see if it does it again if you are so sure!  I would not believe in magic if I were you.